# How to get join events?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I can read messages sent by users, but I don't know how to access events like "USER joined the group".

How can I get them?
I want to welcome new users by my bot as soon as they join. :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll find the key `new_chat_member` in your message whenever someone joins a group.

You then receive the following format

```
"update_id":12595xxxx,
"message":{  
  "message_id":12xxxx,
  "from":{  
     //...
  },
  "chat":{  
     //..
  },
  "date":1461496741,
  "new_chat_member":{  
     "id":12069xxxx,
     "first_name":"Bob",
     "username":"bobbot"
  }
}
```

You can find all the events here:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message

Comment: I saw that bit I cannot make something out of it. I made an if/else to check if a `Message` is a new Member. I print all incoming messages to the console. New users won't come in as a `Message`, otherwise they would be printed too.

Comment: They do come in as a message, I added a sample in my answer.

Comment: Hm ok. I am using the Java api by ruben. Maybe it's a problem from there.